# How to get List of available hosts in SCVMM using powershell command

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Should return only list of hosts available in the SCVMM not it's details.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/virtualmachinemanager/get-scvmhost?view=systemcenter-ps-2019][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this script you gonna get a list of the hosts, and the details of the first one.

To run this script you gonna need the VMM powershell module, that is only available  where the VMM console is installed.

```bsh
## Import VMM module

Import-Module VirtualMachineManager

## Get the VMM server
Get-VMMServer "vmm.contoso.com" | out-null

## Get all hosts managed by the VMM server.
$Hosts = Get-SCVMHost

## Print the hosts list
Write-Host $Hosts

## With this line you gonna print all the attributes of the first host:
$Hosts[0]
```